# I am trying to pull text fields from a form down into mySQL DB and it is giving me trouble

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull text fields from a form down into mySQL DB and it is giving me trouble.

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebChat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="info">
        <h2>Login Here</h2>

        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name"><br><br>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <button style="background-color:#6495ed;color: white;" type="submit"><b>Login</b></button>
        </form>

        <form action="signup.php" method="post">
            <h2>If No Account, Then Sign-Up Here.</h2>
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name"><br><br>
            <label><b>Email-Id</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email-Id"><br><br>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <button style="background-color:#6495ed;color: white;" type="submit"><b>Sign-Up</b></button>

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Connectivity Code

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webchat_data");
//if($conn)
//{
//  echo "hi";
//}
if(!$conn){
    die("CONNECTION FAILED" .mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

My Signup Code

```
<?php
include 'connectivity.php';
$uname=($_POST['uname']);
$email=($_POST['Email']);
$pass=($_POST['Password']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO sign-up(USERNAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD) VALUES('$uname','$email','$pass')";
//$result=$conn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

It doesn't give a connection error, but no data is inserted into my DB.

Comment: You don't check for errors with the connection or the query...

Comment: `sign-up` will cause an issue because `-` is not a valid unquoted character in mysql. You also are open to SQL injections, and should not store plain text passwords. Use error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `-` in the table name and if you do escape it with backtics.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sign-up`(USERNAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD)
```

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-up' at line 1

This would have told you of the error

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

You also are wide open to SQLInjection attacks so please review how to use parameterized queries and prepared statements.

Comment: How to add backticks?

Comment: With the back tick key , right below the Escape key.  AKA the tilde key ~ (if you use shift)  This thing --> `.  However I should add it's best to avoid making table or column names that require special attention.  It's much easier to simply rename the table to sign_up

Comment: I didn't get you sir. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: On your keyboard.  Look to the left top corner.  There is the escape key `ESC` the key below that is the   backtic or if you hit shift its the tilde.  (typically).  Personally I would rename it to `signup` or better still,  `users` if it was me

Comment: yeah thats fine. But still, this isnt resolving the error

Comment: It does fix that error, rather or not there are additional errors, who knows.  With the SQLInjection stuff.  In other words just putting variables in the query, `VALUES('$uname','$email','$pass')` a single `'` quote in any of your inputs will result in a query error.  For example if `$uname = "o'maly"` your query becomes `INSERT INTO sign-up(USERNAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD) VALUES('o'maly','$email','$pass')`  Which is also a syntax error because of this `'o'maly'` which results in an unclosed quote.

Comment: Thanks a ton @ArtisticPhoenix. It worked. Also, could you elaborate on SQLInjection?

Comment: I have no idea what your input data is, so that is one possible failure point.  I also have no idea what your table schema is, so you could have a casing issue, or spelling issue.  Who knows without proper error catching.

Comment: SQLInjection - has been covered many times in much greater detail than I can do here.  I suggest googling it, as it will cover it much better then I can in a simple format like this.

Comment: So should I replace the single quotes with double quotes?

Comment: Basically SQLInjection is when you Inject unsecure data into a SQL statement.  The database can then interpret that unsecure data as part of the SQL command.  A crafty user can Inject values designed to modify the DB, return data that normally wouldn't be returned etc.  Something to avoid.

Comment: A common example is using a SQL string like this for login.  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'`  then I can inject into `$username` this value `$username = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --"` What that will do is change the query to this:   `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --' AND password='$password'` Everything after the `--` is a comment in SQL.  So this would pull 1 user record from the DB and possibly bypass a Login Script, because the variables are not secured.  Or 1 is always true. On top of that I could use OFFSET and iterate through the users

Comment: Which would effectively allow me to login as anyone on the site without knowing either the username or password.  All because the variables are concatenated into the SQL.  Using prepared statements it would look like this.  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?`  (passwords should not be checked against the DB) but the point is that `?` cant be modified and then the data is sent after the query is prepared, the DB knows not to use the data as part of the SQL because its a 2 step process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet (newb) but try adding the backticks `  instead of the single tick parentheses ' .  I notice you are using MySQLi, and I actually began with that but found PDO to be a little more forgiving and open.  Not trying to slap my opinion here but I think you might find it a little nicer to work with using PHP. I also would echo your variables to make sure nothing is null. Any more info you can provide helps too!

Answer (score 0):

You have the basics. All you need to do is check for errors and debug.

```
include 'connectivity.php';
// Not sure why you used parens. You don't need them.
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pass = $_POST['Password'];

// Building a query like this is fine for now if you are just learning.
// This won't work well in real world application.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sign-up` (USERNAME, EMAIL_ID, PASSWORD) VALUES('$uname','$email','$pass')";
//$result=$conn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// mysqli_query returns true or false for insert statements
if ( ! $result ) {
    // Something bad happened
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn). ' POST = ' . print_r($_POST, true));
}
//$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

header("Location:index.php");
```

Comment: sir as you just said that this wont work in real world applications, could you guide me where i need to improve this query, to make it more accurate?

Comment: I recommend you get this bug figured out first. Then, you can use https://codereview.stackexchange.com which is better suited to recommendations than fixing specific problems.

Comment: Sir the bug is figured out. It was the backtick error